# How to fix the error of updating Angular version 14 to Angular version 16?

Tags: angular16

after run ng build this error :

the version of CLI is only compatible with Angular 14.0.0
but Angular version 16.2.12 was found instead.

ng version :
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhYMo.jpg)

I want to update Angular project from version 14 to 16
step by step with this link:
https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-16.0